# want to loop in particular method using performselectoronmainthread

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading

I have to loop in particluar method which do some task. I have used the method performselectoronmainthread wait until done method. Its working fine if i call it for once. But It fails when I call it in for loop. ie 
this is the code:

```
for (int i=1;i<=3;i++) {
            ip=i;
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(createThread:) withObject:ip waitUntilDone:YES];
    }

-(void)createThread:(NSString*)ipIs
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Ip address  is :%@",ipIs);
    [SimplePingHelper ping:ipIs target:self sel:@selector(Result:)];
    [pool release];

}
- (void)Result:(NSNumber*)success {
    //do some stuff

}
```

The problem is that this code works fine when I run this loop once and It calls Result method. But it execution path changes when I try to use loop in performSelectorOnMainThread to pass different variables into it.Then It doesnt call result method.

I am looping because I want to run these same methods on different variables but task to be performed would be same.I am also using waituntil done:YES value..but still it is not working
Any idea ?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not sure what the purpose of createThread method is, but you're blocking the main thread of your app while it runs (waitUntilDone:YES). That's a *terrible* idea, unless you know that it can only possibly take a small fraction of a second. (And if "ip" means "IP Address", and you're doing something network related, then you definitely shouldn't be blocking the main thread while it happens.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try creating other thread

```
myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setupTimerThread) object:nil];
[myThread start];
-(void)setupTimerThread
{


NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];



timer2 = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.04
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(triggerTimer:)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

[runLoop addTimer:timer2 forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[runLoop run];

[pool release];
}
-(void)triggerTimer:
{
//this method will be called in loop set loop interval by setting the timers time duration in above method
}
```

EDIT :

```
int ip=0;
-(void)triggerTimer:
  {
 ip++; // till ip<=3
 [self createThread:ip];
  }
```

Comment: Or u can simply create a timer like in setupTimerThread method but i recommend to do this in secondary thread rest choice is urs..

Comment: yeah..but that wont solve my problem. I want to run createThread method again and again but with different variable(argument "ip=i" ). That would be determined by for loop.The code you wrote would trigger same method after some time(.04) but with same arguments

Comment: What u r doing in for loop try doing it in timer method and call createThread simple like this [self createThread:ip];

Comment: but this variable ip would change each time I call createThread method. So where should I implement for loop?

Comment: whats not working ? u r able to call createThread in a loop or not ?

Comment: sorry for late reply. Actually my charger broke while I was working so giving a late respaonse. Anyways, let me thank you first. your code works fine, the problem was with initilization which I have solved now :). Now again bothering you with my questions:

Comment: 1. The method gets called again and again so I have used [timer2 invalidate] to stop the timer under if condition to stop the timer . Is is good practice. 2) The application quits itself in simulator when timer calls method last time. So I guess some memory problem is occuring. can you help? 3) why my earlier code didnt worked ? It would clear my concepts and elaborate my small knowledge :)

Comment: 1) its the only option to stop the timer its ok to use it . 2)regarding application quit in simulator it might be getting some exception there try to run the app in device in Debug Mode . 3) Once i did the same mistake as urs when i started programming . read about game loops or run cycle of a program .

Comment: also include timer2=nil; in the end after invalidate